# How to set unique id for elements in table after iterating using struts 2 iterator?

Tags: javascript, struts2

I am iterating a list using struts iterator tag as below.

```
<s:iterator var="listItem" value="userMasterActivityDTOList" status="userStatus">
<tr>
    <td width="10%"><s:textfield  name="regIns"  value="%{#listItem.regIn}" /></td>
    <td width="10%"><s:textfield name="regOuts"  value="%{#listItem.regOut}" /></td>
    <td width="10%"><s:textfield name="regDiffs"  value=""/></td> 
        </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

After iterating i want the values of regIns and regOuts textfield in javascript for each row for calculating regDiff.The thing is that i am unable to set unique id's for those textfield in each row so that i can identify them in javascript.

How to set unique Id for each row element?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `index` or `count` property of the iterator-status:

For your code:

```
<s:iterator var="listItem" value="userMasterActivityDTOList" status="userStatus">
<tr>
    <td width="10%"><s:textfield  name="regIns" id="in%{#userStatus.count}" value="%{#listItem.regIn}" /></td>
    <td width="10%"><s:textfield name="regOuts" id="out%{#userStatus.count}" value="%{#listItem.regOut}" /></td>
    <td width="10%"><s:textfield name="regDiffs" id="diff%{#userStatus.count}" value="" /></td> 
        </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

I hope I'm formally correct, it's  been a while since I did JSP.

Answer (score 0):

Use Iterator's status COUNT or INDEX methods.

Count is 1-based, Index is 0-based.

Please refer to: http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/views/jsp/IteratorStatus.html#getCount%28%29

```
 <s:iterator var="listItem" value="userMasterActivityDTOList" 
             status="userStatus">
    <tr>
        <td width="10%">
           <s:textfield  name="regIns" 
                  id="in_%{#userStatus.index}" value="%{#listItem.regIn}" />
        </td>
        <td width="10%">
           <s:textfield name="regOuts" 
                  id="out_%{#userStatus.index}" value="%{#listItem.regOut}" />
        </td>
        <td width="10%">
           <s:textfield name="regDiffs" 
                  id="diff_%{#userStatus.index}" value="" />
        </td> 
     </tr>
  </s:iterator>
```